# pylance not accessed in python

Tags: python, pylance

I am having a problem with pylance .Don't know exactly what it is. attaching a picture.
if I write a code to some game it gives some **"not accessed pylance"** error. if I copy and past the exact code from somewhere then it works. any solutions to solve this please?

Comment: You forgot the picture.

Comment: its not allowing me to post.